# CSS Selector of nested classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm breaking my head with this simple? problem. I know its not a bug nor a cross browser issue, tested on firefox and internet explorer. Simply I don't understand why its resolving this way.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .red_class { color: red; }
    .blue_class {color: blue;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="red_class">
  <a class="blue_class" href="http://somesite.com">Somesite</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my humble opinion both rules have the same specificity so I expected the link to show in BLUE because the blue_class rule is closer, but the link is shown in RED. I actually changed the order so that the ".blue_class" rule was written first, but it didn't change the result

I have found some ways to make the code work, like making 2nd rule more specific, for example:

```
.red_class a.blue_class {color: blue;}
```

But I would really like to understand why this is not working as I expected, that is, if the link has a class blue_class it should be shown in blue.

Really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing in Chrome either. http://jsfiddle.net/9AZvK/

Comment: Perhaps a default browser stylesheet with a more specific selector? what happens if you view the full style tree (e.g. in Chrome tools or Firebug)?

Comment: Which browser(s) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't see how you're getting a red colored link...

Anchor elements with defined `href` doesn't inherits attributes like `color` or `text-decoration`, so the result you're getting it's a little odd.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2

> User agents generally render links in such a way as to make them obvious to users (underlining, reverse video, etc.). The exact rendering depends on the user agent. Rendering may vary according to whether the user has already visited the link or not.

So, this results in a default styled anchor:

```
.red_class{color:red;}

<div class="red_class">
    <a href="#">Something</a>
</div>
```

In this case the anchor inherits the red color:

```
.red_class{color:red;}

<div class="red_class">
    <a>Something</a>
</div>
```

I really don't get the problem, but at least this is an explanation of how anchor styling works.

Answer (score 0):

@Luxfer This is just a simple thing that I do. Download **Firebug Addon** for your **Firefox**. **Inspect** the **element** to which you want to give style. On the **right side** of **Firebug**, there is a box where you can see the **CSS used**. Simply **Right Click** on the CSS pane, there you will find an option as **Add Rule**. As you **Click** on that, it will take the selectors that will target the required element perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain it's not working? Blue is not a good color to test with because most browser default to a blue for hrefs.

```
<div class="red_class">
  <a class="green_class" href="http://somesite.com">Somesite</a>
    <p>More Text</p>
</div>
```

with

```
.red_class { color: red; }
.green_class {color: green;}
```

Seems to work fine in Chrome here. 
[**----Demo-----**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/9AZvK/7/)